# Is there a way to combine duplicates within a large range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, worksheet-function

I have a large (1.7 million rows) table of sales data on a sheet in Excel, many entries of which are identical other than a unique ID and a timestamp. I’d like to consolidate this data by combining the rows that are duplicates by my standards (i.e. only unique in parameters I don't care about).

That alone could almost be accomplished by using the “remove duplicates” function, but I say “combine” because I’d also like the result to sum one of the columns, which represents how many items were part of that particular order.

I’m looking to go from something like this:

```
   A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |    E    |    F    |    “OldSheet”
  OID   |  Client | Program |  Count  |  Status |  Time   |
 436266 | Initech |   SEO   |    1    | Invoiced|  00:52  |
 436267 | Initech |   SEO   |    2    | Invoiced|  01:12  |
 436269 | Initech |   SEM   |    1    | Invoiced|  04:52  |
 436268 |Initrode |   SEO   |    1    | Invoiced|  02:22  |
 436269 | Initech |   SEM   |    3    | Invoiced|  04:52  |
```

. . . to something like this:

```
  OID   |  Client | Program |  Count  |  Status |  Time   |    “NewSheet”
 ...... | Initech |   SEO   |    3    | Invoiced|  .....  |
 ...... | Initech |   SEM   |    4    | Invoiced|  .....  |
 ...... |Initrode |   SEO   |    1    | Invoiced|  .....  |
```

This table is ultimately referenced by several pivot tables, so it needs to maintain the same format.

Comment: Have you tried using a pivot table? No formulae required.

Comment: ...or a database? "GROUP BY"

Comment: Neither a pivot table nor database worked for me, because I needed everything to stay in this exact format for other pivot tables to continue to refer back to it.

Comment: Ah, just seen this after posting my answer... can you edit your question to add this requirement please? It's a crucial detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what a solution using a pivot table might look like.

To achieve the tabular layout go into the Pivot Table Design menu, and change the Report Layout to **Show in Tabular Format**. Turn off sub-totals for each column.

Remember to use a SUM  on your "Count" value field because you have numbers greater than 1 in there.

[image]

Comment: This actually might be easier, Andi. I would just have to paste the pivot back as values once I got it. The main reason I was avoiding pivots is because I’m really bad at them. I didn't know about the tabular format, so this is great.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out in the process of writing this question. My solution was to copy the old table to a new tab, remove duplicates based on only the columns I care about, then place a SUMIFS() formula in the new “count” column that checks each cell in the old tab against the cells in the columns I care about in the new tab and adds up the numbers in the old “count” column for every row that matches all the criteria. Here is my formula (adapted for the example above):

```
=SUMIFS(OldSheet!D:D,OldSheet!B:B,NewSheet!B2,OldSheet!C:C,NewSheet!C2,OldSheet!E:E,NewSheet!E2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In.  It has a Group By command where you can specify the grouping columns and also calculate a Sum or similar Aggregate functions:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/group-rows-in-a-table-HA103993875.aspx

You can output the result to a new Excel Table.